# Envio de Correos Lumen PHP

Tags: php, lumen

estoy haciendo un API-REST con lumen, y esto intentando enviar un correo electrónico en un método de un Controlador, estoy usando PHPMailer, y el problema que tengo es que el email tarda mucho en enviarse y hasta que no se envía la API-REST no devuelve el estado de la request, entonces quería preguntar si podría hacer de alguna forma de que se enviará la solicitud de enviar el correo pero que la request no espere a que el correo termine de enviarse, sino que se envía en "segundo plano" por así decirlo

Adjunto el codigo que tengo actualmente

```
/**
 * Crea un usuario
 * Crea el usuario siempre y cuando se pasen todos los parametros necesarios
 * Comprueba que el usuario no existe ya, si existe no te deja crearlo
 *
 * @param Request $request request en la que van los datos necesarios para la creación del usuario
 * @return $this success true si se ha creado, false si no lo ha echo
 */
public function crearUsuario(Request $request){
    try {
        //Parametros necesarios para poder crear el usuario
        $parametrosNecesarios = [
            'email',
            'password'
        ];
        $this->comprobarRequest($request, $parametrosNecesarios);
        //Si la request esta correcta entonces procedemos a crear al usuario
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $existeUsuario = Usuario::where('email',$email)->first();
        if ($existeUsuario)
            throw new Exception('UsuarioExiste');

        if (strlen($request->input('password')) < 6)
            throw new Exception("LongitudPassword");

        if (!$this->is_valid_email($email))
            throw new Exception("EmailIncorrecto");

        $rol = Rol::where('nombre','Ba')->first();
        $datosUsuario = [
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'rol_id' => $rol->id
        ];
        Usuario::create($datosUsuario);
        //TODO: Notificar al email
        /*$asunto = 'Registro Correcto';
        $body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $altBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
        $host = 'smtp.1and1.es';
        $port = 587;
        $this->sendEmail($email,'alberto@alberto.com','',$port,
            $asunto,$body,$altBody,$host
        );*/
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        return response(["success" => false, "message" => $e->getMessage()], 400)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response(["success" => false, "message" => $e->getMessage()], 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    } catch (FatalThrowableError $e) {
        return response(["success" => false, "message" => $e->getMessage()], 400)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    //Si el usuario se crea correctamente devolvemos true
    return response(["success" => true], 200)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}
```

Comment: Has probado con esto, https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues

Comment: Sii, lo he estado mirando pero no consigo entenderlo, por que vi algo de redis, y hasta donde tengo entendido redis es un tipo de base de datos no relacional, también probe con Beanstalkd pero no me funciono

Comment: beanstalkd es el servicio de encolado(servidor como apache), lo instalas y agregas las clases que indica laravel, una vez hecho eso encolaras ejecuciones (Ejemplo : correo, vista que utilizaras) y un proceso en background estara pendiente de los encolados, en este caso enviar los correos.